# The similarity transformation of Pauli matrices

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, linear-algebra

I am looking for a transformation $S$ of the Pauli matrices ($X,Y,Z$) such that

\begin{align*}
S^{-1}XS=Y, S^{-1}YS=Z, S^{-1}ZS=X.
\end{align*}
Simply put, my question is a cyclic transformation of the matrices $X\to Y\to Z\to X$.

For example, Hadamard matrix $H=1/\sqrt{2}(X+Z)$ gives a transformation $X\leftrightarrow Z, Y\leftrightarrow -Y$ (I don't care the negative factor).
If the transformation exists (or not), I want to know the proof or its mathematics behind it.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try $e^{\frac{i2\pi}{6\sqrt{3}}(\sigma_1 +\sigma_2+\sigma_3)}$ where I used $\sigma_k$ to denote the Pauli matrices

Comment: That is the unitary representation of a rotation around the diagonal of a cube of $2\pi/3$. It is clear that its action on a axis moves it to another axis cyclically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I write here a detailed answer out of my comment.
As is well known, the unitary one-parameter group
$$e^{i \theta \vec{n}\cdot \vec{\sigma}/2}$$
has the property that
$$e^{i \theta \vec{n}\cdot \vec{\sigma}/2} \sigma_k e^{-i \theta \vec{n}\cdot \vec{\sigma}/2} = \sum_{j=1}^3(R_{\vec{n}}(\theta))_{kj} \sigma_j\:, \tag{1}$$
where $R_{\vec{n}}(\theta)\in SO(3)$ is a spatial rotation around the unit vector $\vec{n}$ of an angle $\theta$.

As a consequence, let $\vec{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(\vec{e}_1 + \vec{e}_2+ \vec{e}_3)$ be the unit vector  parallel to the diagonal of a cube with a vertex at $(0,0,0)$ and standard orthonormal axes $\vec{e}_j$. Then the action of a rotation  $R_{\vec{n}}(2\pi/3)$  cyclically superposes the axes.

Taking (1) into account, we have that
$$e^{i \theta \vec{n}\cdot \vec{\sigma}/2} \sigma_k e^{-i \theta \vec{n}\cdot \vec{\sigma}/2} = \sigma_{k'}\:, \quad 
e^{i \theta \vec{n}\cdot \vec{\sigma}/2} \sigma_{k'} e^{-i \theta \vec{n}\cdot \vec{\sigma}/2} = \sigma_{k''}$$
where $k,k', k''$ are a cyclic permutation of $1,2,3$.

$$e^{i \theta \vec{n}\cdot \vec{\sigma}/2}$$
can be explicitly computed by the formula (please check my numerical computation)

$$e^{i \theta \vec{n}\cdot \vec{\sigma}/2} = (\cos \theta) I + i (\sin \theta) (\vec{n}\cdot \vec{\sigma}) = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} I + i \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}} (\sigma_1 + \sigma_2+\sigma_3)\:.$$